# How to show $\{\left<X\right> _ {\infty} < \infty \} = \{ [X]_\infty < \infty \}$ if ${E}\sup_{n\in T}(\Delta X_n)^2 < \infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, quadratic-variation

I need help to show this equality.

$(*)$ $\{\left<X\right> _ {\infty} < \infty \} = \{ [X]_\infty < \infty \}$ if ${E}\sup_{n\in T}(\Delta X_n)^2 < \infty$

I've already show $\{\left<X\right>_\beta<\infty\} \subset \{[X]_\beta<\infty\}$ almost surely

I know, because of the inequality from lenglart$${P}(\left[X\right]_\beta\ge k,\left<X\right>_\beta\le m)\le\frac{m}{k}$$
for  $k\longrightarrow\infty$ follow, that
$$\left\{\left[X\right]_\beta=\infty\right\}=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left\{\left[X\right]_\beta\ge k\right\}}.$$
This imply this equation
$${P}(\left[X\right]_\beta=\infty, \left<X\right>_\beta\le m)=0.$$

For the predicable quadratic variation aplies
$$\left\{\left<X\right>_\beta<\infty\right\}=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}{\left\{\left<X\right>_\beta\le m\right\}}.$$
for $m\longrightarrow\infty$ follows
$${P}([X]_\beta=\infty,\left<X\right>_\beta<\infty)=0.$$ 
The consequence is the claim
$$\left\{\left<X\right>_\beta<\infty\right\}\subset\left\{\left[X\right]_\beta<\infty\right\} \textrm{almost surely}.$$

But now I don't know, how to use this property ${E}\sup_{n\in T}(\Delta X_n)^2 < \infty$ to show $(*)$.

I hope, you understand, what I mean. My english is not the yellow from the egg.

Comment: I forgot to say: $\beta:=\infty$

Comment: and $\Delta[X]_n=[X]_n-[X]_{n-1}=\sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{n}{(\Delta X_i)^2}-\sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{n-1}{(\Delta X_i)^2}=(\Delta X_n)^2.$